# swift save nsdate of core data into a mysql database

Tags: php, ios, mysql, swift

in my swift 2 app the user can save entries into core data.
there is a data row with the nsdate format.

the user select a date with a date picker and store this information into core data, for example:

```
> 2016-03-09 23:00:00 +0000
```

My problem is, how can i save this format into my mysql database?
i can save it as DateTime, but the result will be without the time zone +0000

any ideas? :)

Comment: do you use `$mysql_datetime = date("Y-m-d h:i:s",$swiftDate)` and `date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');`? please watch http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: Problem is, that each user have a different time zone. should i save the date first time for time zone America,LosAngeles and convert it later back to the user time zone? Oo

Comment: Consider saving everything as UTC and display in the timeline of the device the user is currently using

Comment: If you want to send back the time to server that you want, you may try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32406520/convert-nsdate-to-string-with-a-specific-timezone-in-swift